# Is there any way to view the Stack Overflow site without flashing and fixed elements?

Tags: discussion, design, accessibility

I am having a lot of trouble trying to view this site, let alone search it, and I haven't been able to complete the site tour because of the animation. *site flashes* I have sensory processing issues, and need to avoid flashing (such as the right sidebar and occasionally this whole page), blinking, several types of animation, sticky elements, and fixed elements (such as the left sidebar).

Is there any way to view this site without flashing and without fixed elements?

This site *hurts* and I'll need some kind of solution before I can ask questions.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask this, as you’ve already noted. That said, (1) yes, there is also a mobile app, and (2) you shouldn’t be seeing any significant flashing, blinking, or animation, except possibly in one or two ads.

Comment: I also have proprioceptive issues, so I can't use touch devices, as well as the visual processing issues, so I can't withstand the flashing and animation on touch devices.

Comment: Yes. Hide the left nav, disable sticky header (both from your preferences area), and adblock the ads/jobs.

Answer (score 6):

It might help to post some screenshots highlighting which parts of the screen is the problem, and describing the problematic behaviour in more detail.

- [You can hide the static left navigation bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311236/how-can-i-remove-or-hide-the-left-navigation-bar).
- You shouldn't be seeing flashing or blinking.

  The tour has some things moving around, but once you scroll all the way to the bottom and then back up again, it seems that nothing moves any more.
- If the whole site is flashing or blinking, I'm inclined to recommend trying a different browser or checking your operating system or graphics card display settings (but, in either case, you'd probably be seeing the issue on other sites or applications as well).

  Doing either or both of those things might help fix the issue even if it is mostly specific to this site.
- I suppose one thing that could be an issue is the messages that show up when there's a new question in a list, when there's a new answer, when there's a new comment or when a post gets edited - these can cause parts of the page to shift down (I'm not sure there's a way to prevent that currently, but I'm sure adding an option for that for accessibility purposes would get fairly high priority).

  Hovering over "tags" or users (or maybe other things) can also create popups.

  If a post is voted up or down that can also cause dynamic changes to the post score.

  It would help if you could try to check whether any of these things are the source of the problem, and tell us what you find out.

  Although these things happen on many other sites as well.
- If the problem is ads...

  You can always install Adblock.

  But the ads are mostly static, so the only problem I can imagine here is that they maybe take a few seconds to appear.
- As Ed mentioned in the comments, you could possibly also try the mobile app.
- Have you tried disabling JavaScript?

  I haven't really tried this, but I imagine that will fix a lot of issues with things moving on this site, if not all of them.

  On Chrome you can do this on a per-site level, specifically by clicking on Secure in the top left -> Site Settings -> JavaScript -> Block.

  Although the dynamic updates are very useful, and going without them would probably not make the site too much fun to use (you'll need to refresh the page to see updates), so I'd only recommend this as a last resort.

Comment: Also, disabling javascript will disable most functionality of the site, for instance voting or showing full comments list when they are many.

Comment: Thanks. I've disabled the left bar. I'd get flashing from the right and from the whole page. I've looked for other browsers before, but Safari doesn't allow users to disable the blinking cursor, Opera and Vivaldi didn't allow users to disable zooming pain/animation in the new tab window, and Chrome has too much pain/animation in the dowload window. Lynx relies on terminal windows, and I have trouble reading them. I use uBlock origin and various other accessibility extensions. It's possible that there's another conflict with an accessibility extension, but it's not safe for me to check.